# Скрыть маркеры объектов в api яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

В режиме "Вывод списка объектов карты" Api Яндекс карт изначально видны все маркеры из списка объектов, можно ли сделать так, чтобы они по умолчанию были скрыты, а появлялись только после нажатия на ссылку из списка объектов?

Код демо страниц:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Вывод списка объектов карты</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="groups.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{
            width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 450px;
        }
            /* Оформление меню (начало)*/
        .menu {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 0;
        }
            /* Оформление меню (конец)*/
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

первый java

```
// Группы объектов

var groups = [
        {
            name: "Известные памятники",
            style: "islands#redIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.426472, 30.563022],
                    name: "Монумент &quot;Родина-Мать&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.45351, 30.516489],
                    name: "Памятник &quot;Богдану Хмельницкому&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454433, 30.529874],
                    name: "Арка Дружбы народов"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Рестораны",
            style: "islands#greenIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.50955, 30.60791],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Калинка-Малинка&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.429083, 30.521708],
                    name: "Бар &quot;Сало-бар&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.450843, 30.498271],
                    name: "Абсент-бар &quot;Палата №6&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454834, 30.516498],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Спотыкач&quot;"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Оригинальные музейчики",
            style: "islands#orangeIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.443334, 30.520163],
                    name: "Музей грамзаписи и старинных музыкальных инструментов"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.446977, 30.505269],
                    name: "Музей истории медицины или Анатомический театр"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.452512, 30.530889],
                    name: "Музей воды. Водно-информационный центр"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Красивости",
            style: "islands#blueIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.45987, 30.516174],
                    name: "Замок Ричарда-Львиное сердце"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.445049, 30.528598],
                    name: "&quot;Дом с химерами&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.449156, 30.511809],
                    name: "Дом Рыцаря"
                }
            ]}
    ];
```

второй java

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

    // Создание экземпляра карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [50.443705, 30.530946],
            zoom: 14
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        // Контейнер для меню.
        menu = $('<ul class="menu"></ul>');
        
    for (var i = 0, l = groups.length; i < l; i++) {
        createMenuGroup(groups[i]);
    }

    function createMenuGroup (group) {
        // Пункт меню.
        var menuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + group.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Коллекция для геообъектов группы.
            collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, { preset: group.style })
            ;

        // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
        myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
        menuItem
            // Добавляем пункт в меню.
            .appendTo(menu)
            // По клику удаляем/добавляем коллекцию на карту и скрываем/отображаем подменю.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (collection.getParent()) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.remove(collection);
                    
                } else {
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);                    
                }
            });
        for (var j = 0, m = group.items.length; j < m; j++) {
            createSubMenu(group.items[j], collection);
        }
    }

    function createSubMenu (item, collection) {
        // Создаем метку.
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(item.center, { balloonContent: item.name });

        // Добавляем метку в коллекцию.
        collection.add(placemark);
        ;
    }

    // Добавляем меню в тэг BODY.
    menu.appendTo($('body'));
    // Выставляем масштаб карты чтобы были видны все группы.
    myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
}
```

Comment: Все, вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1):

можно убать эту строку

```
        // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
```